# Angular lazy loading... slows page down?

Tags: angular

I've read about using Angular lazy loading to improve page load times, or at least perceived load times. My experience has been that it significantly slows page load time. Because I perceived the page to be slower I ran some numbers. So far, lazy loading is consistently slightly worse.

Does anyone have an explanation?

```
// Regular loading with 'component: MyComponent'

First page load
2.15s   1.49s
2.09s   1.54s
2.45s   1.84s
2.98s   2.25s
2.20s   1.73s

Reload
1.41s   835ms   1.28s
1.56s   529ms   1.40s
1.63s   934ms   1.45s
1.57s   97ms    1.42s

// Lazy loading with 'loadChildren: () ...'

First page load
5.59s   5.12
2.83s   2.24s
2.59s   2.12s
2.6s9   2.04s

Reload
1.72s   1.59s
1.48s   1.34s
1.87s   1.35s
2.06    1.92s
```

Comment: Try to provide a minimal reproducible example. It's hard to analyze without code

Comment: I did. Lazy loading in angular is simple. This is it: use 'loadChildren' instead of 'component'.